# New line in subscript in share latex

Tags: latex, sharelatex

I am trying to shift this extra long subscript to the line below, because it is too long. The code is

`\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{x \in p_{data}(x), z \in p_{z}(z)}`

And the expression looks like :

[image: The current expression.]

I want the characters z onwards to be in a new line, while being the subscript to E.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the whole document including classes used?

Answer (score 5):

you are looking for **substack**

```
\mathbb{E}}_{\substack{x \in p_{data}(x)\\z \in p_{z}(z)}}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are three different specific ways to do this (one command `substack` and one environment `subarray` with at least two different alignment options `l` and `c`), provided by the package [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) (see section 7.1 of the [guide, at page 21](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)). All of them work in inline math mode as well. To type your code, the package `amssymb` is necessary too (although `\mathop{\mathbb{E}}` is maybe redundant).

This code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\substack{x \in p_{data}(x),\\ z \in p_{z}(z)}}
\]

\[
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\begin{subarray}{l}x \in p_{data}(x),\\ z \in p_{z}(z)\end{subarray}}
\]

\[
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{\begin{subarray}{c}x \in p_{data}(x),\\ z \in p_{z}(z)\end{subarray}}
\]
\end{document}
```

gives this output:

[image: screenshot of output]

Answer (score -3):

Instead of `\mathop` directive you can use the following:

```
$\mathbb{E}}_{x \in p_{data}(x),$

$z \in p_{z}(z)}$
```

Which will render this:
[image: final rendering in sharelatex]

## Another alternative

```
$\mathbb{E}}_{x \in p_{data}(x),$

$_{z \in p_{z}(z)}}$
```

which will render into:
[image: 2nd sample image]

Comment: Re-thinking your ask: I don't think it's correct to break a subscript into a separate line, as it messes up readability. How will the reader know that `z \in...` still belongs to the subscript in line above?